# Violation of foreign key constraint JPA

Tags: java, jpa, derby

**Edit: This code actually works correctly. The problem was un-related and was due to a conflicting Entity which was creating a foreign key constraint and stopping me from inserting into the DataFile table.**

I'm having some real trouble with some JPA mappings for a simple `@OneToMany` mapping.

I'm using EclipseLink and DerbyDB.

```
@Entity( name = "study2" )
@Access( AccessType.FIELD )
public class Study2 extends EntityBaseItem {

private List<DataFile> datafiles = new ArrayList<DataFile>();

public Study2() { }

@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
@JoinColumn( name="STUDY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID" )
@Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
public List<DataFile> getDatafiles() {
    return this.datafiles;
}

public void setDatafiles( List<DataFile> dfList ) {
    this.datafiles = dfList;
}
```

DataFile.java

```
@Entity( name = "DataFile" )
public class DataFile extends EntityBaseItem<DataFile> {
    private String filename;
    private long filesize;
    private String fileStatus;
    private String fileType;
    private String fileSubType;

    public DataFile() { }
}
```

This is my EntityBaseItem.java where the `@Id` resides:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBaseItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.TABLE )  
    protected Integer id;

    protected EntityBaseItem() {}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Integer id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override  
    public int hashCode() {  
        int hash = 0;  
        hash += ( this.getId() != null ? this.getId().hashCode() : 0);  

        return hash;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public boolean equals(Object object) {  
        if (this == object)  
            return true;  
        if (object == null)  
            return false;  
        if (getClass() != object.getClass())  
            return false;  

        EntityBaseItem other = (EntityBaseItem)object;  

        if (this.getId() != other.getId() && (this.getId() == null || !this.id.equals(other.id))){  
            return false;  
        }

        return true;  
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I create a Study2 object with some DataFile objects and try to persist it to my DB then I get the error

`UPDATE on table 'DATAFILE' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'DATAFILE_STUDY_ID' for key`

If I change the annotation on getDataFiles() and remove the `@JoinColumn` ( see below ) then the mapping works, however it creates a join table and I'd really rather just have a join column in the DataFile table:

```
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
@Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
public List<DataFile> getDatafiles() {
    return this.datafiles;
}
```

I guess it's down to having my `@Id` in `EntityBaseItem` as when I removed that and added @Id in the `Study2` class then it worked as expected, however there must be some way to keep `@Id` in the `EntityBaseItem` and still use a `@JoinColumn`? I've not had any issues elsewhere in my code, and I have various other mappings which are not as simple as this one.

I know what the error means, however I don't know why it's happening. To me I'd expect my code to work and cascade the DataFiles automatically with a new id for each.

Here is the code that actually causes the error to be thrown:

```
Study2 testStudy = new Study2();
// set some datafiles etc.

EntityManager em = getEM(); // gives me EntityManager
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist( testStudy );
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'd simplified it down to that for testing, throws error on .commit() and then it rolls back the commit.

Comment: Ur mapping is wrong. Giving @JoinColumn on List is not possible saying that Study2 class to hold many keys of DataList table in one row

Comment: @ShoaibChikate If that is the case then what should it be if not List?

Comment: I added answer. Please check

Comment: Where is the code that is causing this exception. What is the foreign key constraint DATAFILE_STUDY_ID?

Comment: @JBNizet I've added the code that causes the exception to the question. I'm not sure what DATAFILE_STUDY_ID is... I don't see anything named that in any of the tables.

Maybe it's because all the items are using GenerationType.TABLE?  From EntityBaseItem, do I need to specify different generation types for each? I only see one SEQUENCE table within my DB, is this normal?

Comment: Yes, that is normal. You should start from the error message and from the SQL query that is executed. It complains about an update query (which one?) and about a violated foreign key constraint named "DATAFILE_STUDY_ID" (how is it defined?)

Comment: @JBNizet I think maybe it's because the study has not been committed previously. Is it the case that the study needs to be added to the EntityManager and then I can set the datafiles? I thought Cascade.ALL would handle this problem automatically.

I am putting a completely new Study2 entity into the DB.

Comment: I don't have the explanation. To me, that should work as well. But I don't have any experience with EclipseLink. If I had to understand where the problem comes from, I would read the generated SQL queries, and I would look at the definition of the problematic foreign key constraint.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank-you! Thanks to your advise to change the foreign key constraint I managed to find the problem.

I had an another entity that was conflicting and making the foreign key constraint with an invalid column name ( one that didn't exist ).

Answer (score 0):

Change your mappings

```
public class Study2(){

@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,mappedBy="study2")
@Access( AccessType.PROPERTY )
public List<DataFile> getDatafiles() {
    return this.datafiles;
}
}
```

Here we say that DataFile is mappedBy "study2" in DataFile class and Study2 has JoinColumn. And the Study2 is inverse side of relationship and will not update the relationship when it gets updated.

Add one field Study2 in DataFile, I have given mapping on field.You can change that

```
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="STUDY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   private Study2 study2;
```

It states that many DataFile are present in one Study2 class

Comment: That's plain wrong. JoinColumn on a OneToMany unidirectional association is perfectly fine. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html

Comment: Yes it is fine, unless, we have JoinTable. OP doesn't have join table.

Comment: No. Read the javadoc again. It says "using a foreign key mapping". It also says: "join column is in table for Order". To map an association with a join table, you use JoinTable. To map an association with a join column, you use JoinColumn. Isn't that logical?

Comment: I agree that and change my answer. But mappings are fine. OP says "If I change the annotation on getDataFiles() and remove the @JoinColumn ( see below ) then the mapping works, however it creates a join table and I'd really rather just have a join column in the DataFile table."

Comment: Hence to have join column in DataFile table, we need to have Study2 field in the DataFile class which will be JoinColumn

Comment: No, you don't. Read the javadoc again. It talks about a **unidirectional** association from Customer to Order, where the foreign key is in Order. Yet the JoinColumn annotation is on the orders field of the Customer class. Just like the OP is doing.